# Is it safe to use one signing key to sign a jwt?

Tags: go, jwt

I'm building a web api in Golang. And I want to implement authentication in this API, so I was looking at JWT.

In the JWT implementation of [dgrijalva/jwt-go](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go), the following example is given:

```
token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
    "foo": "bar",
    "nbf": time.Date(2015, 10, 10, 12, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Unix(),
})

tokenString, err := token.SignedString(hmacSampleSecret)
```

The `hmacSampleSecret` is used to sign the key. Should this `hmacSampleSecret` be a string in a *.env* file for safety reasons? Or should this value rotate and expire once in a while?

If the last is recommended, is there already implementation I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use SHA256 algorithm for jwt signing, then you should generate and store **long random secret** in your .env file.

The secret should be static, don't too much worry about security, It is almost impossible for anyone to bruteforce and find your secret.

You need not to change your secret :)

Comment: The secret can change, but you probably don’t want to do that very often. If you did change your secret the effect would amount to all tokens that have been issued so far becoming invalid, thus all user sessions for example would be logged out.